# How do I get the value of the radio button?

Tags: c#, radio-button

So here are my `options` (names) for the `radio button`:

```
4
2
1
0.5
0.25
```

I tried using this but it's giving me an error:

```
multiplier = Convert.ToDouble(radioButton1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

Error Message:

```
'System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedItem' and no extension method 'SelectedItem' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

How do I set the value of the multiplier based on what the user set in the `radio button`?

Comment: What is the error message???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the error message, `RadioButton` has no SelectedItem property. You should be getting the radiobutton text instead.

```
multiplier = Convert.ToDouble(radioButton1.Text);
```

If you want to check if the radiobutton is selected, use `Checked` property instead

```
if (radioButton1.Checked)
{
    multiplier = Convert.ToDouble(radioButton1.Text);
}
```

In your case you could use a loop

```
foreach (RadioButton d in this.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>())
{
    if (d.Checked)
    {
         multiplier = Convert.ToDouble(d.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the user selects a different radio button? Would it make the multiplier based on the radio button's choice? So if user selected the 4th radio button would multiplier be 0.5?

Answer (score 0):

`radioButton1.Text` will give you the value of the selected item.